# ng-switch not generating the correct code

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, ng-switch

I have the following code in an ionic app, I am viewing the app with ionic serve. However when the first ng-switch statment fires.. for the code

```
<span ng-switch="post.enclosure">             
    <span ng-switch-when="[]"> 
        <p>def</p>                            
        <img ng-src="{{defaultImage}}"style="max-width: 80%!important;">                                
    </span>
    <span ng-switch-default>
        <img ng-src="{{post.enclosure.link}}" style="max-width: 90%!important;">                                                                                              
    </span>
</span>
```

The following code gets generated - why

```
<span ng-switch="post.enclosure">
    <!-- ngSwitchWhen: [] -->
    <!-- ngSwitchDefault:  -->
    <span ng-switch-default="">
        <img style = "max-width: 90%!important;">
    </span>
    < !--end ngSwitchWhen: -->
</span>
```

Why does the image source not come through?

Can I use something else other than ng-switch?

Comment: I generally use `ng-show`

Comment: what values are you getting for post.enclosure ?

Answer (score 1):

You got the second html because ng-switch-when="[]"
Below is the working code like same.

> This code will not work with angular 1.5.0. Please use angular 1.6.0

```js
angular.module("myApp", [])
  .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope){
      $scope.postList = ['post1', 'post2'];
      $scope.defaultImage ="https://material.angularjs.org/latest/img/icons/angular-logo.svg";
      $scope.postImage = "https://itxdesign-itxdesign.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/wordpress-post.jpg";
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
 <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <select ng-model="selectedPost" ng-options="post for post in postList">
  </select>
  <br>
 -------------------- Switching ---------------
  <div ng-switch on="selectedPost">
      <div ng-switch-when="post1|post2" ng-switch-when-separator="|">                 <img ng-src="{{postImage}}" style="max-width: 90%!important;">
      </div>
      
      <div ng-switch-default>
        <div>Default Image:</div>
        <img ng-src="{{defaultImage}}"style="max-width: 80%!important;"> 
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```